# ZE551ML ASUS ZF2, Bootloader failure

Tags: adb, bootloader

I tried to do a procedure described in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BJPEc1NG_k8, about installing Lineage OS on a zenfone 2 ze551ml.
In a specific part of the video, is required to install a new bootloader to be able to install nougat, in the links below therewas two items, one for the ZE550ML and the other one for the ZE551ML, for mistake, i installed the ZE550ML one...
Now i can't see the device with ADB, and it shows only a blank screen.
Some one of you could help me? Anyone got this same issue?
Thank you very much.